# Cypress won't redirect to home after login submit

Tags: reactjs, testing, next.js, cypress

I'm trying to test a redirect after the user login, but its not working. If I do it outside the test it works(it redirects to '/home' page).

The submit is handle with a dispatch from redux, but I don't think that's the problem because I tested before, with some changes and it worked.

This is the login form:

```
const submit = (data: AuthData) => {
    dispatch(login(data));
    router.push('/home');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        {inputs.map((input) => (
          <div key={input.name} className="text-left mb-3">
            <label htmlFor={input.name} className="form-label">
              {input.label}
            </label>
            <Input
              register={register}
              name={input.name}
              type={input.type}
              placeholder={input.placeholder}
              error={errors[input.name]}
            />
            <div className={'invalid-feedback'}>{errors[input.name]?.message}</div>
          </div>
        ))}

        <div className="text-center mt-3">
          <Button className={'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'} type={ButtonType.submit}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

This is the login test:

```
describe('Login Page', () => {
  it('Login correctly', () => {
      cy.get('#email').clear().type('user@mail.com');
      cy.get('#password').clear().type('123456');
      cy.get('.btn').click();
      cy.get('.btn').click();
      cy.get('[data-cy=home]');
    });
});
```

And this is the error that I'm getting
[image]

Comment: It looks like the redirect is happening before the POST to `api/auth/login` completes. The screen shot shows url `/home` but the screen is still on the login page.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I removed the redirect just in case and try to get the footer (a component that you see after login) but still don't get anything. Could it be that I have to handle the state manually? The login change a state that is isUserLogged from false to true. But I don't remember having to do that in the same test I did a week ago that worked well.

Comment: Is it jumping back from `/home` to `/login` because the login hasn't completed? i.e if you visit `/home` before logging in does take you to the login page?